# R remove all numbers after a hyphen, including the hyphen

Tags: r

Here is a super short example from the dataframe that I'm using.

```
structure(list(billing_postcode = c("34990", "34695-4809")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I remove all of the numbers after the hyphen, including the hyphen? I'm working with a column of zip codes and just want the first five numbers all the way through. Although, there may be three-digit zip codes in here also, so I'm looking for a solution that recognizes the hyphen symbol. I know this pattern:

```
gsub("-", "", df$billing_codes)
```

but this just removes the hyphen, and not everything after it, also

Comment: `gsub("-.+", "", df$billing_codes)` . This assumes that you're happy to throw away everything after the hyphen in any circumstances, which I think it sounds like you are from your description of the data in the column

Comment: `gsub("-[0-9]*","", df$billing_codes)` The `*` is greedy and will include all of the numbers after the "`[0-9]`". If there are more strings or objects in that `billling_codes` column after any numbers, they'll be removed as well. I think. My regex knowledge isn't great.

Comment: Someone (possibly the OP) please post the info in these comments as an answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the hyphen in any case, even if it's not followed by anything use `-.*`

- ‘*’ The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
- ‘+’ The preceding item will be matched one or more times.

```
df
  billing_postcode
1            34990
2       34695-4809
3           34695-

gsub("-.*", "", df$billing_postcode)
[1] "34990" "34695" "34695"
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(billing_postcode = c("34990", "34695-4809", "34695-"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```